# How do I get a portable installation of the Rust programming language?

Tags: rust

I've been trying to get a windows installation on a flash drive for a while now.

Comment: First question: why?! Second: I don't think it's possible because you need the systems linker (ld.exe, ld, ld.gold,...)

Comment: Well, I want to bring it around with me to school and home and all that.

Comment: well, read the doc of rustup that simple.

Comment: You can install it per user, you don't need admin privileges for that at all (expect for the mentioned linker)

Comment: @hellow Could you be able to shove a copy of GCC on the device and use it with the 32bit gnu copy? Or is that not a possibility

Comment: It would be possible, but you propably need to build it yourself, because you need a static binary and normally binaries are build dynamically

Comment: @hellow I'm fine with building the binary myself, it's that I needed to get it portable.

Comment: by the way, the best solution is to ask to the admin system of your school to install rust and every tool needed on computer, that his job.

Comment: This really isn't a usefully detailed question -- we don't even know which operating system you're dealing with. A chroot usable across Linux distros is a whole different thing from a Windows binary, f/e, which is different from a portable VM image, which is different from... etc; right now, which of those answers is appropriate can't be distinguished.

Answer (score 9):

Since this question comes up first in the search engine when I searching for installing Rust on a pen drive. I'll answer it.

Installing on pen drive makes sense on Windows, if you want to carry the installation with you.

1. Download rustup-init.exe from the official Rust page (you probably want the 64 bit one nowadays).
2. set RUSTUP_HOME and CARGO_HOME environment variables to point to a location on your pen drive.
3. When you start it will echo back these environment variables. To let you verify it.
4. When asked tell it to customize install.
5. I have portable MinGW on my pen drive so I have chosen x86_64-pc-windows-gnu as the host triplet to install.
6. Tell it to not to alter your PATH, instead have a BAT script that you can start to set these vars for the shell.

I have a BAT script on the pen drive to ensure the PATHs are right despite what drive letter gets assigned, such as this:

```
set DRIVE=%CD:~0,2%

set MINGW_PATH=%DRIVE%\!\Mingw64\mingw64\bin
set GIT_PATH=%DRIVE%\!\PortableGit\cmd
set VSCODE_PATH=%DRIVE%\!\VSCode
set RUSTUP_HOME=%DRIVE%\!\Rust\rust
set CARGO_HOME=%DRIVE%\!\Rust\cargo
set RUST_PATH=%CARGO_HOME%\bin
```

And when you plug in the pen drive to a different computer, then after the install run this bat to have the paths.

---

**Notice: note that this way can not use in ExFAT filesystem. Please see [this issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2680)**

Answer (score 2):

Something like https://www.codejam.info/2015/03/portable-rust-installation.html might work? Possibly with putting the profile script on the drive to be run after inserting? Also, is this for Linux, Windows or something else?

> First, get the binaries according to your system, and the Rust version
> you want. For me (nightly 64-bit Linux binaries) and extract the
> archive (I like to put it in ~/opt):
>
> ```sh
> wget https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
> tar xf rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
> mv rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu rust
> ```
>
> Then, just export the appropriate environment variables (do this from
> your ~/.profile or equivalent to have it set up automatically). No
> need to install anything globally!
>
> ```sh
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/opt/rust/rustc/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> export PATH=~/opt/rust/rustc/bin:~/opt/rust/cargo/bin:$PATH
> ```

Comment: Triple-quotes are a GitHub-flavored markdown extension. We don't support that variant here -- only four-space indents format multi-line blocks as code with syntax highlighting, full-line backdrop, &c.

Comment: BTW, you usually don't need to `export PATH=...`, and certainly not more than once -- just `PATH=...` will change both environment and shell-internal instances of an already-exported variable. (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may not be exported yet, so explicitly exporting *that* one is useful).